# Let $f(x) = \tan ^{-1} x, x \in\mathbb R$, then the sequence $\{ f^{(n)} (0) \}$ is unbounded. True or false$?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

Let $f(x) = \tan ^{-1} x, x \in\mathbb R$, then the sequence
$\{ f^{(n)}(0) \}$ is unbounded. True or false$?$

Is there any short way to solve this?
Finding derivatives is really complicated after a few terms.

Comment: Considering the codomain for $\tan^{-1}$ to be $\left( - \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$, the sequence is identically zero. Therefore, it is bounded.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh $f'(x)=1/(1+x^2)$, so $f'(0)\neq 0$

Comment: I thought it was composition $n$ times.

Comment: If by $f^n(0)$ you mean the $n$th derivative at the origin, use that it can be read off from the Maclaurin series for $\arctan x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*True* is the answer,
and it gets short if the Taylor series
$$f(x)=\arctan x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$$
is available right from scratch. 
Then $f^{(n)}(0)\,$ can be read of from the Taylor coefficients: The non-zero values satisfy
$$\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(0)}{(2k+1)!} = \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\,,$$
thus one has
$$f^{(n)}(0)\:=\, \begin{cases}0& \text{$n\,$ is even}\,,\\
(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\,(n-1)! & \text{$n\,$ is odd}\,.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Using Maclaurin series, the sequence is {1,-1/3,1/5,-1/7...} Which converges to 0, so sequence should be bounded.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please explain more$?$